# How to stringify circular structure to JSON while making and POST API call in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

Sorry for this lame question. I am pretty new to coding

So, I am making an `post` api request with form data in my nodejs app. I am using `https` module of nodejs to do so.
Here is my code

```
app.post("/api/post", async (req, res) => {
  const listID = `a6a85018-3921-11eb-a3d0-06b4694bee2a`;
  const url = `https://api.mailbluster.com`;
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    path: `/api/leads`,
    authorization: process.env.MAIL_API,
  };
  const data = {
    firstName: req.body.first_name,
    lastName: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email_id,
    subscribed: true,
  };
  console.log(data);
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const request = https.request(url, options, (response) => {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    } else {
      res.send(response);
    }
  });
  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});
```

I getting the following error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

I am not sure what else I can do to rectify the error.

Comment: Where is the error thrown exactly?

Comment: @FelixKling I am getting this error in console on line 45, that is ```res.send(response);```

Comment: So, `response` is a complex object: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage. What are you trying to achieve by sending it as is to the client (which obviously doesn't work)? What information do you want to send to the client?

Comment: If you want to get the actual payload of the response you have to listen to the response's "data" event. Have a look at the example here: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback

Comment: So basically, I am trying to post a newsletter subscriber to a list. The subscriber would post his in the form and when he click submit button, the info will be send to Mailbluster. And If no error occurs, the subscriber would be added to the email list. Here is the api docs for this https://app.mailbluster.com/api-doc/leads

Comment: Would you mind simplifying it a bit ? Being a complete naïve, things are tooo much for me to understand.